# Determine eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\underline v$ be a fixed vector such that $|\underline v|=1$ and let
$$
T:E_3\longrightarrow E_3,\qquad T(\underline x)=(\underline x\times \underline v)\times\underline v.
$$
Then

1. All possible eigenvalues of $T$ are greater than $0$
2. No one of other answers
3. All possible eigenvalues of $T$ are less or equal than $0$
4. All possible eigenvalues of $T$ are less than $0$
5. All possible eigenvalues of $T$ are greater or equal than $0$

**My attempt.** By definition, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if there exists $\underline x\neq\underline 0$ such that
$$
T(\underline x)=(\underline x\times\underline v)\times\underline v=\lambda x.
$$
This implies that $\lambda\underline x\cdot(\underline x\times\underline v)=0$, which holds if and only if $\lambda=0$. Then
$$
(\underline x\times\underline v)\times\underline v=\underline0
$$
if and only if $\underline x=k\underline v$, $k\in\mathbb{R}$ (which are the eigenvectors relative to $\lambda=0$). So the correct answer is 2.

Is my attempt right?

Thank You

Comment: Wouldn't $\underline x$ be orthogonal to $(\underline x \times \underline y)$?

Comment: @SubSevn Yes, the condition $(\underline x\times\underline v)\times\underline v=\lambda\underline x$ implies that $\lambda\underline x$ is orthogonal to $(\underline x\times\underline v)$

Comment: So then $\lambda \underline x \cdot (\underline x \times \underline y) = 0$ for all $\lambda$.

Comment: $T(v)=0$, so you can eliminate two possible answers right off the bat.

Answer (score 1):

The identity $\lambda {\bf x} \cdot ({\bf x} \times {\bf v}) = 0$ holds for all ${\bf x}, {\bf v} \in E_3$, because ${\bf x} \cdot ({\bf x} \times {\bf v}) = 0$ does---thus we cannot conclude anything about $\lambda$ from this identity.

**Hint** One option here is to use the dot product expression for the "triple cross product": We have
$$T({\bf x}) := ({\bf x} \times {\bf v}) \times {\bf v} = -(\underbrace{{\bf v} \cdot {\bf v}}_1) {\bf x} + ({\bf v} \cdot {\bf x}) {\bf v} = - {\bf x} + ({\bf v} \cdot {\bf x}) {\bf v} .$$
So, if $\bf x$ is an eigenvector of $T$ of eigenvalue, say, $\lambda$, using the definition and rearranging gives
$$({\bf v} \cdot {\bf x}) {\bf v} - (\lambda + 1) {\bf x} = 0 .$$ Can you take it from here?

> **Additional hint** Consider separately the cases that ${\bf v}$ and ${\bf x}$ are (1) linearly dependent, and (2) linearly independent.

Alternatively, we can recognize our above formula for $T$ as the formula for the orthogonal projection of $-\bf x$ onto the plane orthogonal to $\bf v$.

Comment: If $\underline v$ and $\underline x$ are linearly dependent, then $(\underline v\cdot\underline x), (\lambda+1)\neq0$ and $\underline x=\alpha\underline v$. So, in this case, $\lambda+1=\alpha$. Is it right? If $\underline x$ and $\underline v$ are linearly independent, it results that $(\underline v\cdot\underline x)=(\lambda+1)=0$. But how can I exploit this?

Comment: @Redeldio If $x$ and $v$ are linearly dependent, then $x=kv$ and so $x\times v = $... ?

Comment: @amd if $\underline x=k\underline v$, then the cross product between $\underline x$ and $\underline v$ is zero.

Comment: @Redeldio In particular, if ${\bf x} = k {\bf v}$, then what can you conclude from your observation about $T({\bf x})$?

Comment: @amd I can conclude that $T(\underline x)=\underline 0$. So what are the eigenvalues?

Comment: @Redeldio You’re looking at one of them.

Comment: @amd $\lambda=0$?

Comment: Redeldio, if $\bf x$ satisfies $T({\bf x}) = {\bf 0}$, then $T({\bf x}) = 0 \cdot {\bf x}$, and hence (if $\bf x \neq 0$) $\bf x$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with eigenvalue $0$.